The Usage of "Trisect" in Geometric Constructions
I encountered a scenario where I wanted to describe the behavior of two lines cutting through a specific angle. I wrote :
$$\{\text{Let the lines }  \epsilon,\epsilon' \text{ trisect the angle } A\}$$
However, this phrasing raises a few important questions.
Since traditional angle trisection using only a compass and straightedge is proven to be impossible for arbitrary angles, is it mathematically appropriate to say that lines $\epsilon,\epsilon'$ trisect $A$ by construction? if those lines are drawn using tools beyond the classical compass and straightedge , should I specify how these lines are defined or constructed to avoid ambiguity?
From my experience, in Euclidean geometry problems you are allowed to say : $$\text{Let circle } C \text{have its center on } B \\\text{or} \\ \text{Let the point } x \text{ be the midpoint of the line segment } AB$$
But, both of these can be constructed in any case where you have two points $A,B$ and the classical tools. Nevertheless none of my teachers ever told us what we could construct and what we couldn't . Maybe that is because problems in textbooks are made to have non trivial solutions in the first place but, still , this is something that seems important to me.
Q: Is it "legal" to say By construction I trisect this angle ? If yes , doesn't that mean that many problems otherwise unsolvable in classic axiomatic Euclidean geometry , magically have a solution too?
Thanks for any answers in advance!

Some "unsolvable problems" : $\pi, \sqrt[3]{2}$

There are several tools - look up Kempe's linkage for example - that permit trisections. So, sure, we can construct trisections, we just need to use one of these tools to do it.

It's going to depend on context, isn't it? If you need $c$ or $c'$ as part of a step of a construction that was supposed to be compass-and-straightedge then obviously it's not OK. If $c$ and $c'$ are given among the assumptions of a problem statement then it's OK. There are plenty of "find this angle in this triangle" problems where some of the angles are unconstructable. Other cases depend on the details. But I would never say "by construction" unless I had actually presented a (non-classical) construction. I might say "by assumption" if the circumstances warranted it.

Suppose we could not (at all) trisect an angle. We could still speak about a figure or situation in which the angle were trisected, purely for argument's sake, and it would lead to many interesting results, which we simply could not construct. If I wished to examine Morley's triangle as a construct, which is inherently based on trisections, I would simply assert that the angles are trisected, trusting the reader understands we can't actually make the construct.
But that is not our reality. If someone objected that I can't trisect the angle to study Morley's triangle, I would say I have a trisection tool, and I can prove that it works exactly as needed. There are a number of real inventions, the tomahawk and Kempe's trisector are two that you can buy or build, that allow us to trisect a given angle. Knowing this, unless the situation stipulated only compass and straightedge (or worse, only compass), I would not object to trisection in a construct.
Although what is and is not constructible with which tools is worth knowing and keeping in mind, the reality is our real constructions are riddled with accumulating errors. Brian Moehring pointed out that we cannot construct $\pi$, the old squaring the circle problem. It's good to know that it's futile to attempt construction of pi. But, just for fun, suppose I had a device that could, and suppose I constructed pi. Now let me construct, in reality, an equally good pi, using only straightedge and compass:
Draw a unit circle, draw radii $AB,AC$ at right angles, bisect $AC$ at $M$, $MC$ at $M'$, and $M'C$ at $M''$ so that $AM'' = \frac{7}{8}$. Bisect $AB$ at $N$, draw the circle of radius $BN=\frac{1}{2}$ at $B$, join $M''B$ and where this intersects that circle mark $D$. Draw the perpendicular from $D$ to $AB$ with foot $E$. Join $EM''$. At $D$ draw $DF \parallel EM''$. Then $BF=\frac{16}{113}$. If I add three units to $BF$, $3+BF=\frac{355}{113}$ and you will find this length approximates $\pi$ to $6$ decimal places, an error dwarfed by that of just my first bisection. In other words, even if I had a single-step construct to truly get $\pi$, it would be about as accurate as the one I just made. I enlarged the scale by $1000x$ so you can see $BF \approx 0.1415...$

So, is it material to an argument that I have an actual instrument that trisects perfectly? Not really. I would be just as interested in trisections in the case we could not carry them out physically. If we had an argument for a widget that in principle could trisect, even though we could not assemble the widget, I would accept the overall argument as a construction; if we didn't know of the needed widget, I would still accept the trisection as a premise and follow the argument, but not as a construction. Only if we had proof that such a widget could not exist would I object.
